# BrowserStack's App Automate- Error when running the sample project from the Quick Integration Guide in C#

Tags: c#, automated-tests, browserstack

This is my first time using BrowserStack's App Automate and I downloaded the sample project from the Quick Integration Guide using C#. When I run the tests for the sample project, I get the following errors:

> La commande "dotnet browserstack-sdk --add-patch-bstack
> obj\Debug\net6.0
> C:\Users\edrink\Downloads\nunit-appium-app-browserstack-sdk
> (1)\nunit-appium-app-browserstack-sdk\ios\bin\Debug\net6.0\ios.dll"
> s'est arrêtée avec le code -532462766.

When I click on the error, I'm taken to the BrowserStack.TestAdapter.targets file and this line of code is highlighted:

```
<Exec Command='dotnet browserstack-sdk --add-patch-bstack $(IntermediateOutputPath) $(TargetPath)' />
```

[highlighed code in the BrowserStack.TestAdapter.targets file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li81d.png)

I'm wondering how I can fix this problem and make these tests pass. I have tried looking online and have not seen any corrections for this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please raise ticket with Browserstack at support@browserstack.com